# what does object 'parental' not found in R mean?

Tags: r

I'm trying to check for consistency of variance for residuals with boxplots.
But when I ran the following expression in R:

```
boxplot(split(model$res,parental))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in split.default(model$res, parental) : object 'parental' not found
```

What is it about ?

Comment: FYI: Having more of your code would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Reproducible examples go a long way to getting answers instead of guesses.

Comment: Where did you define parental?

Answer (score 1):

It can't find the `parental` object that you're passing in.  You're probably referencing a field name within a data frame.  So you need to change your expression to be something like:

```
boxplot(split(model$res,data.frame.name[,"parental"]))
```